# Watson Conversation: Add an example with a Entity

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

We have some Intents that almost always include an Entity. How should I add examples for this?

[image]

Here are some samples:

- When can I talk to Shaun?
- Who is Bob?

What I really want to add is

- When can I talk to @sys-person?
- Who is @sys-person?

Watson seems to treat @sys-person as a literal and does not recognize it as an entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK So what you are doing is not possible in that fashion. The purpose of intents is to understand the underlying intent of a group of questions.

You don't need to supply every permutation. Instead just enough for it to understand the jist of what it is people ask. It can then guess on stuff it hasn't seen before.

So your two examples (assuming representative) are what you should put into your training data. That being:

- When can I talk to Shaun?
- Who is Bob?

The system will automatically factor in entities it is trained on to learn. So mentioning two names, means it will give more weight if it sees a different name. But this is dependant on how well trained that intent is.

That said, there is a way to force it to recognise only selective user entities, but it is not recommended, as you lose the meaning of the words. More details on it here:

https://sodoherty.ai/2017/01/16/improving-your-intents-with-entities/

Comment: By output do you mean the example? Just to be clear I want that to be treated as an example of that intent.

Comment: `@sys-person` will display the found entity if a name is mentioned. It doesn't just randomly write names.

Comment: I understand that it will return the entity when I attempt to predict the intent. Just wondering how I enter examples for that intent. I'll try the \ tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: I tried adding the slash before the entity name and it had no effect. I added a picture above to add more clarity to the question.